# How to move a Robot in Reverse in ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a differential drive robot and I am simulating in Stage Simulator. I want to make the robot move in backward direction for a distance of 1 metre. How is it possible? I tried giving it a negative velocity but it does not move.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197787/how-to-move-a-robot-in-reverse-in-ros?/) by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2014-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is exactly how it works. Describe precisely what you are doing.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4